# Maven sees dependent project jar from Eclipse but not from the command line

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm having trouble building my maven project outside of Eclipse. In eclipse, I am able to do it without issues and all dependencies are resolved.

The error I get is that it cannot find the jar file from the dependant project:

```
    myuser@Laptop:~/workspace/Measurement_processor$ mvn clean -X compile        
    Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.
    Apache Maven 3.0.4
    Maven home: /usr/share/maven
    Java version: 1.7.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
    Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
    Default locale: en_IE, platform encoding: UTF-8
    OS name: "linux", version: "3.11.0-17-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
    [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
    [DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
    [DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/myuser/.m2/settings.xml
    [DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/myuser/.m2/repository
    [DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10 for /home/myuser/.m2/repository
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
    [DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
    [DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
    [DEBUG] Project: com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean, compile]
    [DEBUG] Style:   Regular
    [DEBUG] =======================================================================
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building MeasurementProcessor 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
    [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
    [DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
    [DEBUG] Project:       com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
    [DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile]
    [DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
    [DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
    [DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean)
    [DEBUG] Style:         Regular
    [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <directory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
      <excludeDefaultDirectories default-value="false">${clean.excludeDefaultDirectories}</excludeDefaultDirectories>
      <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.clean.failOnError}</failOnError>
      <followSymLinks default-value="false">${clean.followSymLinks}</followSymLinks>
      <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
      <project default-value="${project}"/>
      <reportDirectory default-value="${project.reporting.outputDirectory}"/>
      <skip default-value="false">${clean.skip}</skip>
      <testOutputDirectory default-value="${project.build.testOutputDirectory}"/>
      <verbose>${clean.verbose}</verbose>
    </configuration>
    [DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources)
    [DEBUG] Style:         Regular
    [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
      <escapeString>${maven.resources.escapeString}</escapeString>
      <filters>${project.build.filters}</filters>
      <includeEmptyDirs default-value="false">${maven.resources.includeEmptyDirs}</includeEmptyDirs>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
      <overwrite default-value="false">${maven.resources.overwrite}</overwrite>
      <project>${project}</project>
      <resources>${project.resources}</resources>
      <session>${session}</session>
    </configuration>
    [DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DEBUG] Goal:          org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile)
    [DEBUG] Style:         Regular
    [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <basedir default-value="${basedir}"/>
      <buildDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
      <classpathElements default-value="${project.compileClasspathElements}"/>
      <compileSourceRoots default-value="${project.compileSourceRoots}"/>
      <compilerId default-value="javac">${maven.compiler.compilerId}</compilerId>
      <compilerReuseStrategy default-value="${reuseCreated}">${maven.compiler.compilerReuseStrategy}</compilerReuseStrategy>
      <compilerVersion>${maven.compiler.compilerVersion}</compilerVersion>
      <debug default-value="true">${maven.compiler.debug}</debug>
      <debuglevel>${maven.compiler.debuglevel}</debuglevel>
      <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">${encoding}</encoding>
      <executable>${maven.compiler.executable}</executable>
      <failOnError default-value="true">${maven.compiler.failOnError}</failOnError>
      <forceJavacCompilerUse default-value="false">${maven.compiler.forceJavacCompilerUse}</forceJavacCompilerUse>
      <fork default-value="false">${maven.compiler.fork}</fork>
      <generatedSourcesDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations"/>
      <maxmem>${maven.compiler.maxmem}</maxmem>
      <meminitial>${maven.compiler.meminitial}</meminitial>
      <mojoExecution>${mojoExecution}</mojoExecution>
      <optimize default-value="false">${maven.compiler.optimize}</optimize>
      <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.outputDirectory}"/>
      <projectArtifact default-value="${project.artifact}"/>
      <showDeprecation default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}</showDeprecation>
      <showWarnings default-value="false">${maven.compiler.showWarnings}</showWarnings>
      <skipMain>${maven.main.skip}</skipMain>
      <skipMultiThreadWarning default-value="false">${maven.compiler.skipMultiThreadWarning}</skipMultiThreadWarning>
      <source default-value="1.5">1.7</source>
      <staleMillis default-value="0">${lastModGranularityMs}</staleMillis>
      <target default-value="1.5">1.7</target>
      <useIncrementalCompilation default-value="true">${maven.compiler.useIncrementalCompilation}</useIncrementalCompilation>
      <verbose default-value="false">${maven.compiler.verbose}</verbose>
      <mavenSession default-value="${session}"/>
      <session default-value="${session}"/>
    </configuration>
    [DEBUG] =======================================================================
    [DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/myuser/.m2/repository)
    [DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/myuser/.m2/repository)
    [WARNING] The POM for com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
    [DEBUG] com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [DEBUG]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.3:compile
    [DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.3:compile
    [DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.3:compile
    [DEBUG]    org.testng:testng:jar:6.8.7:test
    [DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
    [DEBUG]          org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
    [DEBUG]       org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
    [DEBUG]       com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.27:test
    [DEBUG]       org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.12:test
    [DEBUG]    de.congrace:exp4j:jar:0.3.11:compile
    [DEBUG]    joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
    [DEBUG]    com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.602s
    [INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 25 19:22:18 GMT 2014
    [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/102M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project MeasurementProcessor: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project MeasurementProcessor: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:375)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:183)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:358)
        ... 24 more
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:528)
        ... 26 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Here is the project's pom:
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            4.0.0

```
        <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>MeasurementProcessor</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>MeasurementProcessor</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8.7</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.congrace</groupId>
                <artifactId>exp4j</artifactId>
                <version>0.3.11</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
                <artifactId>CommonLibraries</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

As you can see it's dependent on com.mydomain:CommonLibraries, which has a pom.xml as follows:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.mydomain</groupId>
        <artifactId>CommonLibraries</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>


        <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            </plugins>
            </build>

            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.8</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.28</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.8.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.6</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

The ultimate goal is to get this to work on jenkins, but the first step is to get it to run on terminal.

**UPDATE:**

I cleaned up (deleted) directories with compiled sources in the repository for mydomain and then reran the install for the CommonLibraries. That worked!

I got errors after that, but they were related to me having test classes dependent on TestNG in the main folder. It now works.

Comment: so jar com.mydomain:MeasurementProcessor:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT exist in local m2 repo ?

Comment: Have you tried installing `com.mydomain:CommonLibraries` before building your project?

Comment: Completely unrelated but, as the author of HikariCP, I see you are running 1.2.8.  We fixed several critical bugs between that release and the current 1.3.0.  I would suggest updating your dependency.

Comment: @NiksTyagi: I assume you meant CommonLibraries.jar, and yes. After reading your Comment, I deleted the odd versions in the repository that were in there and ran mvn install, which created the jar (also answer to @Joao). The jar for MeasurementProcessor is not showing up. I am getting a different error, I will update above.

Comment: @brettw: Thanks, updating the dependency. I am going to use [1.0.0,2.0.0) as the version so I keep up. Is this safe?

Comment: I would recommend not using ranges for production software because your dependencies might update at an inconvenient point in your development cycle invalidating all your testing and other Q&A work.

Comment: It is "safe" in the sense that we will probably never release a broken HikariCP, but as noted above, it should typically be a conscious decision to update.  In our company, typically after every new release it is time to check for new versions of our dependencies and update for the next release.  In this way we keep current and allow time for the new dependencies to "bake in" over the course of developing the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run "mvn clean install" for the project responsible for the com.mydomain:CommonLibraries:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT artifact so it gets created in the Maven repository.

The behavior you see is because m2e can resolve artifacts from Eclipse projects directly.

Comment: I did indeed omit the clean install originally. It did only work after manually deleting the previously created jars from the m2 repository. Not sure if that is the right way of doing it (I read and tried `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` which did not work for me)

Comment: Artifacts are expected to be permanent and static unless you are using SNAPSHOTS.

Comment: And normally when I want to clean the respository, I just rename .m2/repository (and delete it later).  Requires downloading a bit, but  is easily reproducible.